# check if there is no an empty rows in JTable befor saving with push button?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

hi guys i have a question about checking for empty rows in JTable to tell user that you forget something before saving data with bush button.. i have 18 columns and unlimited rows so what i want is to creat a method that can i call with ok_btn or i have to creat somthing inside action of button itself..

```
ok_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
if (not empty){
//do somthing
this.dispose();
else{
JOptionPaneShowMessageDialog(null,"you forget something!");
}
```

i want to check for column 7 & 12!

thanks in advance

Comment: You know, it would be better to have your model take care of this. The model could return all the rows with empty values in it.  This saves on the need to loop of 1000's of rows and columns, which could become time consuming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know structure of your table or tablemodel, but you can do it in this way:

```
ok_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

 boolean isEmpty = false;
 for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++) { //for column 7
     if (jTable1.getValueAt(i, 7).toString().equals("")) {
           isEmpty = true;
           break;
     }
   }

   if (!notEmpty){
      //do somthing
      this.dispose();
   else{
      JOptionPaneShowMessageDialog(null,"you forget something!");
}
```

Comment: just worked fine thank you... may i update the code in the answer for other people?

Answer (score 1):

OK here is my code after i updated it:

```
private void btn_OkActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           


              boolean isEmpty7 = false;boolean isEmpty12 = false;
     for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) { //for column 7
         if (table.getValueAt(i, 7).toString().equals("0.0")) {
               isEmpty7 = true;
               break;
         }

       }
     for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
        if (table.getValueAt(i, 12)==null) {
               isEmpty12 = true;
               break;
         } 
     }

       if (!isEmpty7&&!isEmpty12){
          //do somthing
          this.dispose();
       }else if (isEmpty7&&isEmpty12){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"you forget something");
       }else if(isEmpty7){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"you forget row 7");
       }else if (isEmpty12){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"you forget row 12");
       }
    }
```